# Use LS_COLORS (not LSCOLORS) on Mac OS

Tags: zsh, macos

LSCOLORS does not give a lot of options or control for directory listings. I've tried several ways to use LS_COLORS (the standard method for such things) without success. Is it possible to bypass LSCOLORS and use LS_COLORS directly? (zsh shell, Catalina)

Comment: You mean the *Linux* method for such things.  BSD `ls` uses LSCOLOR.  There's no "bypass".

Comment: I just discovered gls, however, which does the job (and can be aliased to ls as 'gls --colors')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of those variables has any special meaning to zsh. They are solely used by `ls`, which is **not** an internal program to zsh. However, you have two `ls` at your disposal on macos:

The `ls` which comes with the OS, is the BSD variant, and as you can see from the man page, it reacts on `LSCOLORS`, provided that coloring is enabled (`CLICOLOR="Yes"`).

Then you can install the Gnu Tools on your Mac, which brings you GNU ls (depending on how you installed them, invoked via `ls` or via `gls`), and this `ls` obeys the variable LS_COLORS.

Hence, it all depends on which `ls` you are using...